# "Feature" (mining terminology)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "feature" in the following examples?

They are positioned at a crossroad (registered under **feature** number 1291) and are dated to 1st half of the 20th century.

Few of the examples (**feature** 1166 – 1174) can be found at the north-western end of the Rudničko brdo north.

**Feature** consists of one massive trench that has been excavated in the base of the hill, with orientation running from northeast to southwest.

The purpose of the latter structure is difficult to ascertain, but it is not impossible that all these **features** together formed a complex of mining operations.

Comment: 'a part of a building or of an area of land: _a geographical feature_ Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: This seems to relate to a particular map.  And "feature" just means "Thing on the map"

Comment: @JamesK No, this is archaeology.

Answer (score 2):

In archaeology, feature is:

Features
Features in archaeology — also known as “cultural features” — are non-portable (cannot be moved) artifacts such as storage pits, garbage pits, graves, hearths, wells, cellar holes, and stone walls.

[feature](https://diggingintothepast.org/glossary-of-archaeology/#:%7E:text=Features%20in%20archaeology%20%E2%80%94%20also%20known,cellar%20holes%2C%20and%20stone%20walls.&text=A%20piece(s)%20of%20stone,and%20removed%20from%20a%20core.)

This is not mining terminology. It is archaeology.

Answer (score 0):

[Merriam-Webster definition 3.a for ***feature*** as a noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feature) says *“a prominent part or characteristic”*. The usage in your examples above (“…feature number 1291…” and “(feature 1166 - 1174)”) implies that there is a map or other document in which notable objects and/or locations are numbered, and these are being referenced by those numbers rather than [repeatedly] using a longer description such as ‘the 45m rise 300m south of the southern edge of the main excavation site’ or some similar complex description.